# jQuery parents() - processing each tier separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent

When I have a class that matches several elements is there a way to process each tier of parents inidividually

```
$(".myWidespreadClass").parents() // [immediateParent1, immediateParent2, deeperAncestor1, deeperAncestor2]
```

I would like to be able to run something like .each() but where the first iteration runs over immediate parents, the second over deeper ancestors at the next level etc...

Comment: A recursive function using `parent()`?

Comment: You mean, iterate recursively over parents?

Comment: Checkout the parentsUntil function: https://api.jquery.com/parentsUntil/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fascinating question. I think you'll want a loop, something like this:

```
var parents = $(".myWidespreadClass").parent(); // Not plural!
while (parents[0]) {
    // Process them, e.g.
    parents.each(function() { /* ... */ });

    // Get the next tier
    parents = parents.parent(); // Not plural!
}
```

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/egejer) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/egejer/edit) - **Update** but see below, that could terminate early

<s>You may want to terminate a bit earlier than that, e.g.:</s>

```
while (parents[0] && parents[0].nodeName !== "BODY") {
```

...depending on your needs. I did in the example. See below.

**Update** Actually, you have to be careful with the early termination, probably better off filtering when you're processing the parents instead, something like this:

[Live example](http://jsbin.com/owukij) | [Live source](http://jsbin.com/owukij/edit)

```
var parents = $(".myWidespreadClass").parent();
while (parents[0]) {
    // Process them, e.g.
    parents.each(function() {
        if ($.contains(document.body, this)) {
            // This one is under `body`, process it
            display("Visiting " + this.nodeName + "." + this.className);
        }
    });

    // Get the next tier
    parents = parents.parent(); // Not plural!
}
```

The reason being that your initial set of elements may be at wildly different levels in the DOM, and so you'll reach the topmost element for some of them sooner than for others. The `body` check above may not be appropriate for your needs, but you get the idea.

Comment: You beat me on this :) btw, why did you use parents[0] as a condition? wouldn't be better something like a recursive function.. ? http://jsfiddle.net/R6XJ7/7/ Anyways, +1

Comment: @redShadow: I used `parents[0]` to keep the loop going for much the same reason you used `!elem` to terminate your recursive function. :-) Nice recursive take on it. Recursion isn't necessary here, so I wouldn't say it was better, but it works just as well.

Comment: Cheers - great answer. But one more difficulty with elements being at different levels in the DOM is that using parents() you will process each element at most once, but with the parent() + iterator method it's possible to process some elements more than once... which is more a problem with the tier not being well-defined in all cases than with your approach. I may try and develop this into a plugin which takes an argument specifying whether or not elements should be ignored if they've already been processed once

Comment: @wheresrhys: Ah, yes, good wrinkle. Easy enough to do (maintain an array of the ones you've visited, perhaps), but very good point.